# SmalltalkHub versus SqueakSource3

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

With the next closing of [SqueakSource](http://www.squeaksource.com) repository, I wonder what is the advantage of [SmalltalkHub](http://www.smalltalkhub.com) over [SqueakSource3](http://ss3.gemtalksystems.com). Is there some feature missing in SqueakSource3?

I have noticed that basic functionality like [explore](http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/explore) projects seems broken in SmalltalkHub, which is understandable because it is still in beta, but why to move or register projects to SmalltalkHub then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pharo's core development happens completely on SmalltalkHub.

It is much faster than SqueakSource3, which is the main point in favor of it. SmalltalkHub is still being extended and new features are on the way. For a typical use case from the image side there is little or no difference between the two.

Comment: As current maintainer of SqueakSource3 i can say that man-power-wise SmalltalkHub has a clear advantage, its release cycle is shorter and new features are added faster.

However, to my knowledge, SmalltalkHub does not yet provide to browse the source-code online.

I plan to provide a carnary site for new features of SqueakSource3. Stay tuned :)

Comment: As promised in the previous comment, the SS3 canary site  is available at http://canary.netshed.de/

Answer (score 3):

SmalltalkHub is faster than SS3. It has a new look. You can manage team and collaborators with a modern interface. Nicolas Petton uses it daily for work and in addition it will continue to enhance it. All the Pharo core packages are hosted there. Finally, you can also easily install and use SmalltalkHub in your company if you need it. The software stack behind SmalltalkHub is really robust and nice. Several companies uses it for other projects.

Comment: Nice to see you here @StephaneDucasse :)

Answer (score 2):

From a risk-avoidance POV, there is something to be said for storing them in both. Their software stacks and feature sets are sufficiently different. Just make sure you identify one as primary. Copying the monticello files [from one repository to the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454965/how-to-copy-several-monticello-commits-from-local-repository-to-smalltalkhub-com/17456510#17456510) is easily automated. Stef provided some scripts to copy whole projects from squeaksource to smalltalkhub recently, they would equally well work for canary or ss3.

Comment: Stephan, could you please add the link to the scripts which automated copying from one repository to the other? Are they here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454965/how-to-copy-several-monticello-commits-from-local-repository-to-smalltalkhub-com/17456510#17456510 ?