# How to copy several Monticello commits from local repository to Smalltalkhub.com automatically?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I commit several versions of Monticello packages to a local repository on my disk during the day.

At a later time I want to sync the local repository with a Smalltalkhub.com repository.

At the moment I copy the local commits manually one by one to the Smalltalkhub repository using the Monticello browser.

How can i automate this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Gofer](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/Gofer.pdf) to automate your Monticello tasks.

```
 Gofer new
   package: 'MyProject-Core';
   package: 'MyProject-Tests';
   url: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/USER/MyProject/main/' username: 'USER' password: '***';
   push.
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Gofer chapter of the "deep into pharo" new free book (pharo by example two - http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/pbe2/.) I presented Gofer in details. In particular I present some ways to migrate between repositories
The default for Gofer is fetch and pull, based on that you can easily build sync.

For example if you use Smalltalk hub

```
Gofer new
  smalltalkhubUser: 'PharoBooks' project: 'GoferExample'; 
  package: 'PBE2GoferExample';
  package: 'PBE2GoferExampleSecondPackage';
  push.
Gofer new
  smalltalkhubUser: 'PharoBooks' project: 'GoferExample'; 
  package: 'PBE2GoferExample';
  package: 'PBE2GoferExampleSecondPackage';
  fetch
```

You can also obtain some information as follows

```
((Gofer new
  smalltalkhubUser: 'Pharo' project: 'NativeBoost'; allResolved)
     groupedBy: [ :each | each packageName])
```

Now you can also migrate

```
 | go |
 go := Gofer new squeaksource3: 'Pharo20'. 
 go allResolved
    do: [ :each | self crLog: each packageName. 
        go package: each packageName;
        fetch]
```

Then once you get the files in your local directory you can push to another repository.

```
  | go |
  go := Gofer new.
  go repository: (MCHttpRepository
                   location: 'http://ss3.gemtalksystems.com/ss/rb-pharo' 
                   user: 'pharoUser' 
                   password: 'pharoPwd').
  (((FileSystem disk workingDirectory / 'package-cache') allFiles 
       select: [:each | '*.mcz' match: each basename])
                    groupedBy: [:each | (each base copyUpToLast: $-) ]) keys 
                                            do: [:name | go package: name; push]
```